# Parameters indexing issue in Context Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made an iNoteBook project, and in this project of iNoteBook, I used the React Context API and have a problem. I showed in below screenshot of my code.

```js
import React from "react";
import NoteContext from "./NotesContext";
import { useState } from 'react'

const NoteState = (props) => {
  // const s1 ={
  //     "name": "salman",
  //     "class":"11th"
  // }
  // const [state, setState] = useState(s1)
  // const update=()=>{
  //     setTimeout(() => {
  //         setState({"name": "Zaidi",
  //         "class":"12th"})
  //     }, 2000)
  // }
  const host = "http://localhost:5000"
  const InitialNote =[
    {
      "_id": "6574a2e28578c1b1d01908fc11",
      "user": "6571ce3a431ff5a369bb3146",
      "title": "title",
      "description":"description",
      "tag": "tag",
      "date": "2023-12-09T17:24:50.190Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]

  const [notes, setNote] = useState(InitialNote)        
        
  // Get all Note
  const getNotes = async () => {
    // Api call
    try {   
      const response = await fetch(
        `${host}/api/notes/fetchallnotes`,
        {
          method: "GET", 
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "auth-token": "...."
          }
        }
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
  
      const json = await response.json()
      console.log(json , 'this is my json')
      setNote(json)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching notes:", error);
    }
  }

  // 1 Add Note
  const addNote = async(id, title, description, tag) => {
    // Api call
    const response = await fetch(
      `${host}/api/notes/addnote/${id}`,
      {    
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "auth-token": "...."
        }
        // body: JSON.stringify({title , description , tag}), 
      }
    );

    console.log(id, "NoteState line 73")
    console.log(title, "NoteState line 74")

    // TODO APi call
    const  note = {
      "_id": "6574a2e28578c1b1d01908fc11",
      "user": "6571ce3a431ff5a369bb3146",
      "title": title,
      "description":description,
      "tag": tag,
      "date": "2023-12-09T17:24:50.190Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
           
    setNote(notes.concat(note) )
  }

  // 2 Delete Note
  const deleteNote = async(id) => {
    // TODO APi call
    const response = await fetch(
      `${host}/api/notes/DeleteNote/${id}`,
      {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "auth-token": "...."
        }
      }
    );
    const json = response.json(); 
    console.log(json)
    console.log("Deleting it with id : " + id)
    const newNotes = notes.filter((note) => {
      return note._id !== id
    })
    setNote(newNotes)
  }

  // 3 Edit a note
  const editNote = async (id, title, description, tag) => {
    // Api call
    const response = await fetch(
      `${host}/api/notes/updatenote/${id}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "auth-token": "...."
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title, description, tag }), 
      }
    );
    const json = response.json(); 
      
    // logic to edit 
    for (let index = 0; index < notes.length; index++) {
      const element = notes[index];
      if (element._id === id) {
        element.title = title
        element.description = description
        element.tag = tag
      }
    }
  }

  return(
    <NoteContext.Provider value={{ notes, addNote, deleteNote, editNote, getNotes }}>   
    {/* value={{state , update} */}
      {props.children}
    </NoteContext.Provider>
 )
}
 
export default NoteState
```

So at line number 61 of this code `addNote = async(id, title, description, tag) => {` I am using `id`, `title`, `description`, and `tag` so when I `console.log(id)` it has the title value and when I `console.log(title)` it has the description value.

I tried to making add notes projects and a problem which explained appearing.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

If the `addNote` function signature is

```js
const addNote = async (id, title, description, tag) => { ... }
```

and within this function the `id` argument has the `title` value, and `title` has the `description` value then it seems the issue is that you are passing the arguments to `addNote` in the incorrect order when it is called.

I suspect you are forgetting to pass an "id" value as the ***first*** argument and are likely doing something like `addNote(title, description, tag)`. The first argument passed is assigned to local variable `id`, the second to `title`, and so on.

## Solution

Ensure you are passing all the required `addNote` function arguments in the correct order.

Example:

- Pass an "id" value as the first arg

  ```js
  addNote(id, title, description, tag)
  ```
- Pass `undefined` to "skip" the first arg if it isn't required (*this is unlikely based on the implementation though*)

  ```js
  addNote(undefined, title, description, tag)
  ```
- Update the `addNote` function signature to take a single object argument so the "order" becomes irrelevant.

  ```
  const addNote = async ({ id, title, description, tag } = {}) => {
    ...
  };
  ```

  Then any of the following calls are valid and acceptable:

  `addNote({ id, title, description, tag });`
  `addNote({ title, description, tag, id });`
  `addNote({ description, tag, id, title });`
  `addNote({ tag, id, title, description });`
  `addNote({ title, description, tag });`
  `addNote({ description, tag, title });`
  ...
  `addNote({ tag, title });`
  ...
  `addNote({ description });`
  ...
  `addNote({});`
  `addNote();`

You will likely want to add some checks/guards to the `addNote` implementation to ensure you are not making invalid API requests and other invalid use cases. You will also want to get into the habit of using functional state updates so you don't accidentally enqueue a state update from a stale closure.

Example:

```
const addNote = async ({ id, title, description, tag } = {}) => {
  if (!id) return;

  try {
    // Api call
    const response = await fetch(
      `${host}/api/notes/addnote/${id}`,
      {    
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "auth-token": "......"
        }
        // body: JSON.stringify({ title , description , tag }), 
      }
    );

    console.log(id, "NoteState line 73")
    console.log(title, "NoteState line 74")

    // TODO APi call
    const  note = {
      "_id": "6574a2e28578c1b1d01908fc11",
      "user": "6571ce3a431ff5a369bb3146",
      "title": title,
      "description":description,
      "tag": tag,
      "date": "2023-12-09T17:24:50.190Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
           
    setNote(notes => notes.concat(note)); // <-- update from previous state
  } catch(error) {
    // Catch and handle/ignore any Promise rejections or thrown errors
  }
};
```